# How to create Tagged PDF using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, tagged-pdf

I have successfully generated Tagged PDF using PDFMark in \special{ps: } via DVI->PS->PDF method. Now I am trying to achieve the same in XeLaTeX and not success. Can anybody help me to put PDF tags using \special{pdf: } method for XeLaTeX?

Regards,
Johny

Comment: Would you please provide a small example that works with `dvips`, just to see what might be done to achieve the same with `xelatex`.

Comment: Here are the macros \def\docinfo{%
\special{ps:
[{Catalog} <</MarkInfo <</Marked true>>>> /PUT pdfmark
}}%

\def\startdoc{%
\special{ps:
[/Subtype /document /Lang (en-US) /StPNE pdfmark 
[/\string_objdef {dta1} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{dta1} <</O /XML-1.00 /Author (Johny)>> /PUT pdfmark
}}%

\def\enddoc{%
\special{ps:
[/StPop pdfmark
}

\def\para{%
\special{ps:
[/Subtype /p /StPNE pdfmark
[/StBMC pdfmark
}}%

\def\endpara{%
\special{ps:
[/EMC pdfmark
[/StPop pdfmark
}}%  Use these commands at begin and end document and paragraphs. Refer to Adobe's PDFmark_Reference guide for details.

Comment: @Johny The code you posted contains lots of unmatched brackets. Please edit your question: provide  a small example and corrected code.